# How to duplicate a SQL database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I need to redo some data types in a lot of tables in my SQL database and it says I need to rebuild the table, but I am very cautious on doing this because I am not certain on how to do it and dont wanna loose all the data. So I decided to try to copy the database and use it as a testing playground. The problem is I can not find how to do it or if I do its a solution form 2006 and the software interface has changed a lot since then.

Comment: The easiest would probably be creating a backup and reattaching the backup under a different name ...

Comment: You could right click the table and select script table as, then tweak this to create the new table i.e. Table1 becomes Table1_New with your data type amendments and then use `INSERT INTO` built from cast/converting on your original table.   Once happy, this can be your new table.

Comment: @derpirscher Do not add confusion by abusing terminology. One cannot "reattach" a backup.

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL Server, the easiest way to copy your DB with another name is the copy data wizard which is available under task menu.

Right-click on DB you want to copy --> Tasks --> Copy database

It will ask basic info like source and destination server, login credential etc and will copy the DB.

[image]

If you using Azure SQL DB, then below command will copy any database on same server.

```
Create Database New_database_name as copy of Database_you_want_To_Copy
```

Comment: Do you need certain permission to acess this because my tasks list is only half the size of yours

Comment: "You must be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role on both the source and destination servers"....More about copy database wizard here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Also, the copy option is not available on sqlexpress